# PHP usort function to sort array that has incrementing elements

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have a dilemma. Because I'm using Amazon's MWS, I have to get the order of the array exactly as Amazon would before I hash the contents otherwise the hash that I make and the hash Amazon makes won't match and Amazon won't accept my feed.

While I know of PHP's `usort` I've never used it, so I'm not sure quite how to create a function that does what I need.

Here's the array:

```
Array (
    [0] => AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXX
    [1] => Action=ListInventorySupply
    [2] => MarketplaceId=XXXXXXX
    [3] => ResponseGroup=Basic 
    [4] => SellerId=XXXXXX
    [5] => SellerSkus.member.10=SKU10
    [6] => SellerSkus.member.11=SKU11
    [7] => SellerSkus.member.1=SKU1
    [8] => SellerSkus.member.2=SKU2
    [9] => SellerSkus.member.3=SKU3
    [10] => SellerSkus.member.4=SKU4
    [11] => SellerSkus.member.5=SKU5
    [12] => SellerSkus.member.6=SKU6
    [13] => SellerSkus.member.7=SKU7
    [14] => SellerSkus.member.8=SKU8
    [15] => SellerSkus.member.9=SKU9
    [16] => SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256 
    [17] => SignatureVersion=2 
    [18] => Timestamp=2016-04-06T22%3A26%3A41Z 
    [19] => Version=2010-10-01
)
```

The problem is that Amazon's sort is just slightly different:

```
Array (
    [0] => AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXX
    [1] => Action=ListInventorySupply
    [2] => MarketplaceId=XXXXXXX
    [3] => ResponseGroup=Basic 
    [4] => SellerId=XXXXXX
    [5] => SellerSkus.member.1=SKU1
    [6] => SellerSkus.member.10=SKU10
    [7] => SellerSkus.member.11=SKU11
    [8] => SellerSkus.member.2=SKU2
    [9] => SellerSkus.member.3=SKU3
    [10] => SellerSkus.member.4=SKU4
    [11] => SellerSkus.member.5=SKU5
    [12] => SellerSkus.member.6=SKU6
    [13] => SellerSkus.member.7=SKU7
    [14] => SellerSkus.member.8=SKU8
    [15] => SellerSkus.member.9=SKU9
    [16] => SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256 
    [17] => SignatureVersion=2 
    [18] => Timestamp=2016-04-06T22%3A26%3A41Z 
    [19] => Version=2010-10-01
)
```

You'll see that the keys for the first three `SellerSkus.member.{#}` elements are different. I need to be able to keep the remaining sort the same, except that when there are 10 or more SKU's it needs to sort like Amazon's sort.

I've read the [PHP doc for usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), but I'm still not getting anything that works above 10 items. It seems like I have to keep track of the `SellerSkus.member.{#}` number, in order to sort them correctly, but I haven't the foggiest idea of how to do that with `usort`. Any guidance in the right direction would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `natsort`, it finds the numeric part of the string and sorts it numerically.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. `natsort` takes those elements `SellerSkus.member.10` & `SellerSkus.member.11` and places them behind the element `SellerSkus.member.9`. What's strange is that on the `natsort` page, it shows a "Standard sorting" section that sorts the values just as I need it, however, that's not how `sort` or even `asort` is actually sorting the array.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I thought you wanted them in numeric order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want an ordinary lexicographic sort, but only using the part of the string before `=` when comparing. So your comparison function should find the `=`, get the substring before that, and compare them.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a = substr($a, 0, strpos($a, '='));
    $b = substr($b, 0, strpos($b, '='));
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: First of all, thank you! Second of all, I had to read your answer three times for me to figure out what 'lexographic' meant! Hahaha. I appreciate it!